# I want to send MMS from a computer to my cellphone. How do I format text?

Tags: php, email, mobile-phones, mms

What markup language is used when sending MMS via email?  I'm using PHP to send myself MMS via email from my server.  But I don't know how to control layout and appearance.  For example, I can't figure out how to make text bold, or change the color.

Comment: Looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimedia_Messaging_Service, the E-Mail format might be gateway specific - maybe it's best to ask the mobile provider? No idea, I have no experience in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MMS doesn't support special text formatting such as bold or italic!

Only the Enhanced Messaging Service (EMS) provides it. But in my opinion that's no good choice (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_Messaging_Service) because the most devices to not support EMS.